# webkit appearance - textarea background: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

I have a webkit appearance issue.  What I am trying to accomplish is to use a division as a contenteditable division with the webkit appearance of a textarea.  This works wonderfully until I attempt to remove the background.  I can change colors without issue but removing it is proving futile.  I have tried using a transparent image for the background but the appearance of the text area seems to overwrite it to a specific color.

The question is, is it possible to set the css to background: none; when using appearance.

I put together a jsfiddle as a bit of further explanation.

```
.div1 {width: 350px;
height: 100px;
-webkit-appearance: textarea;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMkv3/2/)

PS. I hope I did this right : )

Comment: I don't see any background on `.div1` on Chrome 26. Works for me so far. Isn't there any other style involved?

Comment: I think the background is added in when -webkit-appearance is used.  I believe it defaults to white.  What I am attempting to do is change the background of the div which now looks like a textarea to none or transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use `-webkit-appearance`**.

WebKit is applying the default styling for a textarea to your div.

**CSS**

```
.div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    background: none;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: monospace;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

textarea {
    background: none;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/eMkv3/5/**

Answer (score 0):

Just change the color of your background to

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

This will make the background transparent.  If it's going to be zero alpha (opacity) you can make the RGB whatever color you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/eMkv3/7/

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like on my browser:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Has no effect.  It does take effect if I set the color to:

background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 100);

Comment: I guess I'm missing something.  It's already transparent (on chrome 26) and adding that color to anything should make it transparent.

Comment: Hmm, I too am on Chrome 26 and the result of your jsfiddle is a white background.
Now I am absolutely puzzled.

Thank you for the screenie.  I'll report back with a wtf.